# SQL Error: ORA-01847

Tags: sql, oracle, date

When i try to execute the below query

```
insert into TEST (PROCESSING_START_DATE)
values (to_date('05/13/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

I'm getting below error

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

and `PROCESSING_START_DATE` is of type `DATE`

The output of `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TEST') from dual` is:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST" (
    "PROCESSING_START_DATE" DATE
 SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
```

Comment: What's the output of `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TEST') from dual`?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE "TEST"
   ( 
 "PROCESSING_START_DATE" DATE
   )  SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING`

Comment: Are you connected as the same user, so inserting into the same schema and the table you think you are? Is there a trigger on the table? Do other dates work OK? If so please show some that do and any others that don't, copying and pasting exactly what you're running from SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a trigger or whatever involved, I just don't believe you. I think this should work independent of any NLS setting.

This works for me:

```
create table HVBTEST (D date);
insert into HVBTEST (D) values (to_date('05/13/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Did you really test this directly with SQL*Plus?
Or is this part of an application and you only *think* your code executes this?